# Day or Days Format based on Integer Value in PHP

Tags: php, format, ternary

Here is [Sample Code](https://eval.in/819225): -

```
<?php

    function ConvertintoDays($seconds) {
    $zeroSecond = new DateTime("@0");
    $givenSeconds = new DateTime("@$seconds");
    return $zeroSecond->diff($givenSeconds)->format('%R%a days');
     }

echo ConvertintoDays(86400);
```

of which following will be output: -

```
+1 days
```

Now, by English Grammar, I want to output +1 Day instead of +1 Days.

Please help me with any ***shorthand Ternary Logic***.

With thanks,
Sukumar

Comment: `format('%R%a day(s)')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, store the formatted day, then use the ternary operator:

```
<?php

function ConvertintoDays($seconds) {
    $zeroSecond = new DateTime("@0");
    $givenSeconds = new DateTime("@$seconds");
    $day = $zeroSecond->diff($givenSeconds)->format('%a');
    return ($day == 1) ? '+'.$day.' day' : '+'.$day.' days';
}

echo ConvertintoDays(86400);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator and add the `+` manually in the return statement.

```
<?php

    function ConvertintoDays($seconds)
    {
        $zeroSecond = new DateTime("@0");
        $givenSeconds = new DateTime("@$seconds");
        $day = $zeroSecond->diff($givenSeconds)->format('%a');
        return '+' . (($day == 1) ? $day . ' day' : $day . ' days');
    }

    echo ConvertintoDays(86400);
?>
```

Example: https://eval.in/819252